# apex:inputfield can only be used with sobjects with a wrapper class

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I'm getting below error when I used `<apex:inputfield>` instead of `<apex:inputtext>`,

> apex:inputfield can only be used with sobjects or objects that are
>   visualforce field component

But my requirement is to have `inputfield` so that a lookup to the user will be generated based on the lookup relationship given to the field.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!items}" var="item" columns="6" id="thetable">
                <apex:column headerValue="Internal Receipient">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!item.internalrec}"/><!-- **This should be Input field (Lookup Field)>Make field Required** -->
                  </apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

**Controller Class**

```
public class BonusSplitclass {

public list<Fields_List> items;
    public void setitems(list<Fields_List> fielditem){
        items = fielditem;
    }
    public list<Fields_List> getitems(){
         if(items.isempty()){
            items = new list<Fields_list>();
            }
        return items;
    }
 public BonusSplitclass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            string id = Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
            items = new list<Fields_List>();              
            for(integer i=0; i<5 ;i++){
                Fields_List fl = new Fields_List();
                bonus_split__c bs = new bonus_split__c();
                fl.internalrec = bs.Internal_Recipient__c;
                 items.add(fl);
}
Public class Fields_list{

    public string internalrec{get;set;}
}
}
```

Comment: You didnt paste` Fields_List` code?

Comment: This is the basic code I have written. What should be their in fields_list code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you should use the apex:inputfield tag to make use of the default field functionality (lookup field in your case).

Second, you are using the value of 'internalrec' which is a regular String field instead of the Internal_Recipient__c (which I presume is the lookup field?) field from the Bonus_split__c Custom object.

In this case you should store the Bonus_Split__c record (for example as: public Bonus_Split__c bs) in the Fields_List wrapper class to call it in VF page like: {!item.bs.Internal_Recipient__c}.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

I have updated code to use field(Internal_Recipient__c) instead of string(internalrec) for input field,

Vf Page

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!items}" var="item" columns="6" id="thetable">
                <apex:column headerValue="Internal Receipient">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.b.Internal_Recipient__c}"/><!-- **This should be Input field (Lookup Field)>Make field Required** -->
                  </apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

Controller Class

```
   public class BonusSplitclass {

    public list<Fields_List> items;
        public void setitems(list<Fields_List> fielditem){
            items = fielditem;
        }
        public list<Fields_List> getitems(){
             if(items.isempty()){
                items = new list<Fields_list>();
                }
            return items;
        }
       public BonusSplitclass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
                string id = Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
                items = new list<Fields_List>();              
                for(integer i=0; i<5 ;i++){
                    bonus_split__c bs = new bonus_split__c();
                    Fields_List fl = new Fields_List(bs);
                     items.add(fl);
                }
      }
      Public class Fields_list{

        public bonus_split__c b{get;set;}

        public Fields_list(bonus_split__c bs){
            b=bs;
        }
      }
    }
```